# Compare strings that have white space on the left side

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hello I am  comparing two strings..
But how to identify that they both are deference/same if one is having white space like,

```
a=ASHUS<br>
b=ASHUS     (Second one with white space on left side)
```

Now I want to check whether both values are same or not.(According to my code, they both are different)

```
if($qOpt1a==$qOpt2a or $qOpt1a==$qOpt3a or $qOpt1a==$qOpt4a or $qOpt2a==$qOpt3a or $qOpt2a==$qOpt4a or $qOpt4a==$qOpt3a){
    echo "<script>
            alert('Option should not be same');
          </script>";
}
```

Comment: Is this a javascript question? Or do you want this in php or mysql? Each of those is a different environment. *php Mysql* means about as much as *English Arabic.*

Comment: [trim](http://php.net/trim)

Comment: As answered by Black-Hole use trim() , this ensures that there wont be any white space on both the ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). it'll remove white space on both sides, if you want to only remove white space in left side you can also use [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

Answer (score 1):

To compare two strings, ignoring leading white space, you can use `ltrim`:

```
if (ltrim($str1) === ltrim($str2)) {
    // strings are the same, ignoring leading white space
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In php:   `$var1 == ltrim($var2)`

This trims leading spaces from $var2 then compares it to $var1.  Notice that `trim()`, `ltrim()`, and `rtrim()` are fairly sophisticated.